# Blockqoute text on downvoted and grayed out posts is invisible in meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

See [this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/863/52).

The text in blockquote is invisible unless it is selected. Tested on Chrome 16 running under Ubuntu.

Comment: Also verified with Safari on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.

Answer (score 2):

Verified this with Firefox on Windows, so I guess it's pretty universal...