# Should this "list question" really have been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question: [Is there a website that shows which SF book/film awards there are?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/478/is-there-a-website-that-shows-which-sf-book-film-awards-there-are) was recently closed as a list question.

I'm happy for this to be closed if it should, but based on the meta question: [Are list questions allowed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/are-list-questions-allowed)

This question doesn't have a googable answer and isn't a poll.

Should it really have been closed?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This may be a "list" like question, but it generates GREAT content for the site and the internet, and doesn't seem to generate too many "Me too" answers.

Answer (score 2):

I might be open to editing this question to something like the following, then reopening:

> What awards specifically track SF books and movies? How can I find lists of works that have received these awards?

Unlike our garden variety list-of-works question, the list is somewhat manageable and the criteria for inclusion are mostly clear. Still, the list is very long, longer than I'd imagined, and that's a bad sign.

Asking for sites that list awards is too far removed. Stack Exchange is not a repository of pointers, it's a repository of knowledge.

I don't feel very strongly about this.

### A wiki would be the ideal format, really.

<circle color="red" style="machine-drawn">

> **The [awards](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awards) tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it?**

</circle>

Comment: I think you hit the key complaint I have about the question when you say that asking for sites that list awards is too far removed. As it is worded now, its arguable that it isn't even a scifi question, but rather a question about websites (that happen to host scifi-relevant information).

Comment: @Gilles - could you please expand on your 3rd paragraph? I hold a 180 opposite opinion - I feel that having a pointer to a "professionally" (or designatedly) maintained list is a lot better than having a list SFF.SE would have to maintain, especially if the most important elements of the list are also included in the answer (or a snapshot at the time).

Comment: @DVK So you look for a list of SF awards and find a link to a link to a link to a link to a link to a list of SF awards. Happy? We don't want to contribute to that madness (especially considering the probability that one of these links is dead). I remember Joel wrote strong words about this somewhere, can't find the place now though.

Comment: @Gilles - a mite of strawman there? I'm perfectly happy to prohibit any answers that are links to links; and definitely will delete any dead link answers if I ever see one (only happened to see one in my entire SO career). Also see my addendum - I would STRONGLY prefer a link to a list to ALSO have a "best of" exerpt or even a "as of" snapshot. P.S. You didn't address my "not up to date list from 1 year ago" concern.

Comment: @DVK Then have both. In the tag wiki. Is anyone against closing this question and moving the content to the [tag:awards] tag wiki?

Comment: @Gilles - Do people know to find this info by going into tag Wiki? I most certainly didn't tumble onto the fact that tag wikis existed for a fairly long while. Q&A is a lot more visible/accessible IMHO. How do you feel about keeping the question around (and open) BUT migrating the **answer** contents into a tag wiki and linking that from a single "community" answer?

Answer (score -1):

I closed it as a list question because of the open nature of the question.  The answer boils down to yes or no.  If the answer is 'No', then I doubt anyone could post that as an answer with certainty.  But every 'Yes' answer will have a single link to an example, which is what your question was attracting.

If you can rework you question so it only has one objectively valid answer, instead of numerous equally valid answers, which will continue to attract 'me too' answers that accumulate over time, I'll gladly reopen it.  Otherwise, this type of question leads to a messy list of examples, and encourages future open-ended questions along these lines.

Comment: Are there REALLY that many sites which **list** SF book awards? So far, there were 3 good answers (I added mine due to explicit "would like non-english too" confirmation by OP, and one me-too answer that IIRC was the first chronologically and can't be begrudged. As usual, there seems to be a "this WILL generate bad content" guessing game on moderators' part, with the guess being wrong.