# Questions about identifying stories are on topic according to the faq!

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

Please reopen [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33733/identify-a-western-story-comics-or-movie-which-a-black-or-asian-hero-heroine-pla), which after editing is on topic according to this FAQ item:

- Story Identification

Why did no users, mods, or repliers inform me or edit it?

Comment: I edited your question here to improve grammar, if I messed up one of your points, it can be edited further.

Comment: *"Please identify a western story, comics or movie which a black or Asian hero/heroine has the positive first role."* That sentence makes it a list question.  Furthermore, western, comics, and movie are not necessarily on topic. Just because it is a comic doesn't mean it is a science fiction / fantasy comic.

Comment: My mean of western is some which has made in western countries. And about not mentioning the word science fiction I supposed it is clear enough which my mean is science fiction as this site is for this reason not the other kinds.

Comment: @Keen Thanks for edit! I think it is correct enough now. I had not edited it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bottom line is this. Story identification questions are on topic. However, if there are so few details such that any number of stories could fit that example, they are not allowed. For instance, there once was a user who asked a question saying something to the effect of "I remember watching a movie with a time traveling robot. What is it?". That just doesn't give any clues, and could be interpreted any number of ways.

Your question reads "Please identify a western story,comics or movie which a black or Asian hero/heroine has the positive first role." There are any number of stories, movies, etc which fit that criteria. If you are looking for a specific story, you need to include more details. Things such as when you heard about it, where you were, etc, all clues that you are focusing on a specific story. The question you gave is similar to the Time Traveling Robot, there are just too many examples to make this work.

The best questions on Stack Exchange have answers which can be clearly identified, and require some explaining. Opinion is okay, but there should be a solution.

Some small list type question are allowed, BTW, so long as the list is relatively narrow. Naming every Dr. Who actor would be allowed, for instance, but not a question as generic as this one.

Comment: I had missed the word "science fiction". Really if you look at answers do you think there are many stories,comics and movies made in western countries which there is a black or Asian the first positive role as a hero/heroine. From what I have gained as answers I do not think so. Anyway I think most downvotes were because of misunderstanding of voters and a little because of getting the question which I confess had many careless mistakes. Anyway I agree with you and appreciate your convincing answer.

Comment: I do not know why you got downvotes?! Is there anyone who is angry because of a good answer which is not insulting the others and doesn't try hate talk?

Comment: @PersianCat the next issue if we don't think there are too many possible answers (I still believe there are!) there is the issue that too many unknown answers may appear at some later date. So we have two issues: There is no one true answers, in fact whatever answer being picked is likely to be subjective. And secondly, whose to say that the 50 answers we get today will still be as 'complete' tomorrow? At some point there won't be anymore Dr Who actors to list, however I doubt there will ever be a finite list of Black Protagonists in Science-Fiction or fantasy!

Comment: @Pureferret You convinced me completely about the matter. Agree! It seems reasonable.

Comment: @PersianCat I'm glad we agree, this is a similar but different [question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11911/3804), that might help you see a good example question. If you want more examples, do you want to discuss this in [chat]?

Comment: -1 for time traveling robots. :)

Answer (score 6):

There appears to be a language issue here.

Story identification, as listed in the FAQ, means "I once read/saw a story, but I can't remember what it was called; please someone help me find the title".

What you are asking is "please list any number of stories that meet my criteria".

Please see [this meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17/1359) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 relevant parts of the site FAQ in play here.  The first is under *What kind of questions can I ask here?*:

> Story identification

This links to the [story-idenfication](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-idenfication) tag, which has a tag excerpt of:

> Questions asking for help identifying a TV series/episode, comic-book issue/story arc, movie, book, or other story.

So these are about questions where a person is looking for one specific story that they cannot recall the title of.

The second FAQ entry is under *What about other Science Fiction and Fantasy related questions?* which has some examples of questions that are off-topic here:

> Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: What are all the books that have X? Who wrote about topic Y?

This is they type of question you're asking.  You're asking for a list of works that have X, where X is a black or Asian hero/heroine protagonist.  These sorts of questions lead to an unending list of answers as people add a couple of examples in each answer.  This doesn't work on a Q&A site, where each question is expected to have some sort of finite, reasonably-sized answer, and so they are off-topic.

Comment: +1 Good points!